# Using custom Angular attributes inside TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE editor to manage my website built with Angular 4.

Everything is working fine except when I add the `routerLink` attribute to an `<a>` tag inside the tinyMCE editor, the `routerLink` becomes `routerlink` (not camel cased).

here is my code for tinyMCE initialization:

```
var editor_config = {
   path_absolute : real_url,
   selector: "#postTextArea",
   valid_elements: '*[*]'
}

tinymce.init(editor_config);
```

I allowed all attributes but cannot make the routerLink work.
TinyMCE always changes it to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `routerLink` is not valid HTML5 - attributes in HTML5 are all lowercase.

To see what I mean try this in any modern browser console:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<span ID="x" myCustomAttr="x"></span>';
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

...this produces...

```
<span id="x" mycustomattr="x"></span>
```

TinyMCE is simply doing to the attribute what the browser will do at runtime.  *It wants to always create valid HTML.*

Angular uses something called Normalization to deal with browsers and attributes.  You can read about it here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive/#normalization

you should be able to use `data-router-link` which TinyMCE should be fine with as its valid HTML5.

Comment: I don't think `data-router-link` works on angular 4.. tried changing the `routerLink` to `data-router-link` on my app to test and it didn't work

Comment: Perhaps you could convert `routerlink` back to `routerLink` when the form is submitted and before you save the data?